# Не работает window.onload

Tags: javascript, модули

Разестил в Html файле следующий код:

```html
<script src="script.js"></script>
<script src="admin.js"></script>
```

В обоих js файлах главные функции находятся в window.onload, то есть в файле script.js, как и в admin.js код следующий:

```js
window.onload = function () {
  //сама функция
  
}
```

Проблема в том, что если я подключаю сначала script.js, а потом admin.js, то код находящийся в window.onload исполняется только в admin.js. Если я меняю местами подключаемые файлы, то исполняемый код также меняется на соответствующий.

Интересно также то, что код, находящийся вне window.onload, выполняется в обоих файлах, а в window.onload - только в последнем.

Как решить проблему?

Comment: `window.addEventListener('load', function() { ... })`

Comment: @andreymal по прежнему не работает

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том, что при добавлении через присваивание `window.onload = function` эта присвоенная функция переписывается той, которая присвоена последней.

При добавлении функций в качестве обработчиков событий через `window.addEventListener` эти обработчики накапливаются и выполняются согласно очерёдности при добавлении.

Следующим образом будет всё исполняться:

```js
//код из файла script.js

window.addEventListener('load', function()
{
 console.log('script.js');
}, false);

//код из файла admin.js
window.addEventListener('load', function()
{
 console.log('admin.js');
}, false);
```

```html
<script src="script.js"></script>
<script src="admin.js"></script>
```